# What does the sign ⩚ (LOGICAL AND WITH MIDDLE STEM) mean?

Tags: logic

I found the sign ⩚ (LOGICAL AND WITH MIDDLE STEM) on my computer, but I have never seen this sign before, so I am eager to know the meaning of the sign.

Comment: Where exactly did you find this symbol? A lot of Unicode characters are just not used.

Comment: Yes, actually I found it at Moji-viewer (macOS).

Comment: What's Moji-viewer? @yudukikun5120

Comment: Sorry for perplexing you. [Moji-viewer](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A2) is a tool of the Japanese version of macOS. It is the same as the Unicode viewer.

Comment: I can't find any mentioning of this other than in unicode character listings, but it's part of the supplemental mathematical operators which contain a huge number of symbols that I've never seen before and that seem derived from well-known symbols. So perhaps they're just there to give people options to use ad-hoc symbols if they need to define new operators for a specific purpose. Here's the list:  https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Block=Supplemental_Mathematical_Operators:]

Comment: Perhaps try to search for "unicode supplemental mathematical operators" and find out why this block was added to the unicode definition. I don't know if there are technical documents that describe the purpose of each character block.